# How to display unicode characters in Angular Material Tooltip

Tags: angular, unicode, angular-material, tooltip

does anyone know how to display unicode characters in a matTooltip? I tried the following:

```
<span matTooltip='CO\u2082'>Dummy Text with Tooltip</span>
```

But it's unfortunately displaying CO\u2082 and not CO2 (damn I don't even know how to display unicode characters in stackoverflow, I want a subscript 2 obviously! :))

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alexander shows you as passing as variable. I suggest you to pass it wrapping in single quote. That will also work.

```
 [matTooltip]="'CO\u2082'"
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tooltip-material-kyixca?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip%2Fbasictooltip.html)

Comment: Nice, that's even better for my personal case, because I don't need the variables. The brackets around the matTooltip did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

You add add the unicode string to a variable and bind it to matToolTip

Component

```
toolTip='CO\u2082'
```

Template

```
[matTooltip]="toolTip"
```

Comment: can you show us an example as I tried your code but not getting desired result.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f9pchy?file=src/app/tooltip-overview-example.ts

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly fine! I marked Afsar's answer as the solution, because I don't need an additional variable in this case.